# 2005-2006 года рождения или годов рождения

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

«...первенство  Симферополя по лёгкой атлетике среди юношей и девушек 2003-2004, 2005-2006 года рождения». Верно здесь употребление «года рождения», несмотря на то, что их как бы два периода?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос № 204700
В каком числе употребляется слово год\годы в словосочетании 1988-1990 года\годов рождения?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**В единственном числе: *1988-1990 года рождения*.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Грамота не всегда дает объяснения, часто ограничиваясь одними ответами.
Поэтому я поясню **свою точку зрения.**

Я полагаю, что  ***оборот 2003 года рождения*** является несогласованным определением для всех юношей и девушек, рожденных в этом году.

В сочетании ***среди юношей и девушек 2003–2004 года рождения*** перечисляется группа юношей и девушек, рожденных в указанный ПЕРИОД в **два года**, то есть это такое же определение для **этой группы**.

Запись 2003–2004 года рождения  обозначает **единый  интервал времени** продолжительностью в 2 года, то есть в 24 месяца. Дословно это будет звучать так: **с 2003 года до 2004 года,** то есть мы видим, что здесь **единственное число**. Интервал не делится на года, поэтому нет  числа множественного .

А далее **перечисляются разные группы**, причем каждая из них имеет своё несогласованное определение. Количество групп не имеет значения, в данном случае это две группы.

Comment: но ведь периодов два...

Comment: _Sharon: Запись 2003–2004 года рождения обозначает единый интервал времени продолжительностью в 3 года, то есть в 36 месяцев._ === Гм... И ведь два человека уже поверили в это!

Comment: Ну поверили, так надо же уметь убеждать (шутка). Да, ошиблась немного с математикой, так это же мелочи, исправлю. Здесь другое важнее: на проблему надо смотреть чуть СВЕРХУ, иначе за деревьями леса не заметишь (что и видно по недавним ответам). «Какие бабочки, букашки!... А видел ли слона? Каков собой на взгляд!...Слона-то я и не приметил». А вот моя собственная ошибка показалась мне интересной. Это, безусловно, было происками деструктивных сил и вбросом в сознание ложной информации. Мне показалось, что за тире непременно прячется третий элемент множества, иначе там было бы не тире, а союз И.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, если бы даже один период был, всё равно года разные, их несколько, значит, нужно множественное число.

Вот пример из "Новостей":

> 6 апреля стартуют переходные игры Открытого первенства Москвы среди
> команд 2004-2006 годов рождения.

Вот если бы мы перечисляли их по отдельности, мы бы писали во множественном числе: В соревнованиях принимают участие спортсмены следующих годов рождения: 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006.